# Javascript regex: Use encodeURIComponent with replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been trying to figure out the smartest (and most efficient) way to replace plain text URL's with an `a href`, and somehow involving the `encodeURIComponent()` function.

**The code I have come up with so far looks like this:**

```
var regex = /(\b((https?):\/\/|(www))[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]*)/ig;
$(element).replaceWith(element.textContent.replace(regex, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>'));
```

Now I am trying to figure out the best way to use `encodeURIComponent()` on the result (but still only on the `a href`, the visible link should be left without that change).

**Inputs:**

```
1. My website at http://example.com/ is awesome
2. My website at www.example.com is awesome
```

**Expected Outputs:**

```
1. My website at <a href="http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F">http://example.com/</a> is awesome.
2. My website at <a href="www.example.com">www.example.com</a> is awesome.
```

Which would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) callback. The matches can be used inside the callback function and for `href` attribute, `encodeURIComponent` can be used.

```js
var str = `1. My website at http://example.com/ is awesome
2. My website at www.example.com is awesome`;

var regex = /(\b((https?):\/\/|(www))[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]*)/ig;
str = str.replace(regex, function(m, e) {
  return '<a href="' + encodeURIComponent(e) + '" target="_blank">' + e + '</a>';
});

console.log(str);
document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: Yea, I know. But what If I want to keep my original code `$(element).replaceWith`?

Comment: @Robin Use the updated `str`. `$(element).replaceWith(str);`

Comment: Ah yea, you are right. Marking as the answer, nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Group-Operators for that:

Search for

```
^(.*)(http:\/\/|www\.)([^\s]*)(.*)$
```

and replace by

```
$1<a href="$2$3">$2$3</a> is awesome.
```

[See https://regex101.com/r/mT5hQ4/1](https://regex101.com/r/mT5hQ4/1)

```
var re = /^(.*)(http:\/\/|www\.)([^\s]*)(.*)$/mg; 
var str = '1. My website at http://example.com/ is awesome\n2. My website at www.example.com is awesome';
var subst = '$1<a href="$2$3">$2$3</a> is awesome.'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

With this you can add `encodeURIComponent()` easily

Comment: Yea, I know. But what If I want to keep my original code `$(element).replaceWith`?